# How to validate antd form fields using jest/enzyme while simulating submit click

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, antd

I am using jest and enzyme for unit testing. I have a login form and now wants to write test cases for it. How can I validate the values I have passed. Suppose I simulate email field with abc@gmail.com. I need to check these values at the time of submitting the form.

Comment: Any updates on this ?

Comment: @Niki Yes I got the solution for it. What I did is I had Form inside my wrapper. So find Form from your wrapper, and check it's props. There you will get instance of form which you can use to get the state of your antd form.
Like wrapper.find(Form).props().form.getFieldsValue(fieldName);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution for it. What I did is I had Form inside my wrapper. So find Form from your wrapper, and check it's props. There you will get instance of form which you can use to get the state of your antd form.

```js
wrapper.find(Form).props().form.getFieldValue(fieldName);
```

Comment: I keep getting a `Cannot read property 'getFieldsValue' of undefined` error. Any ideas what this could be, or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: For me it worked but I am interested in validation, so it seems that antd is validating it async because this is the snapshot ```<FormItemInput name={{...}} className="form-item" rules={{...}}
                                                      touched={true} validating={true} errors={{...}}``` and still cant access validation message